# Overwriting in a loop For

Tags: python, opencv

I am a beginner in coding with Python and OpenCV, and I have a problem with my program. My aim is to detect any obstacle on the rails. To achieve this project, I'm using a function to sustitute the background. At the beginning, I had one background and different photos with an obstacle to train. But some photos with an obstacle didn't work with the background I had.

That's why I decided to take different background photos. The idea is to create a code which will do a subtraction with different background, till it really works. Here is an example : I have a photo with an object. The code will substitute the first background from the photo with an object. If it doesn't work (the code doesn't detect the object after this application), then it will try again with the second background and so on.

Once it will find the right background to substitute from the photo with an object (it means that the code will return the original photo with a rectangle around the object), then it stops. Of course, we don't need to try with the other backgounds left because we already have a good result now.

So my problem is : I am trying to do this with the code below, but it doesn't work. If, for a photo with an object, a particular background works for example, then if the loop FOR (line 22) begins to deal with this background, it will work because the loop will stop just after this first iteration. But if this background is on the second iteration or more, then it doesn't work anymore. I think that each time I come back again in this loop, I am overwriting on the last frame I created. I mean, instead of subtracting "backgorund 2" from "the photo with an object" in the second iteration for example, I think I am subtracting "backgorund 2" from "the photo with an object AND background 1", or something like this. I am not 100% sure but it is an hypothesis.

I would be really grateful if someone could tell me why it doesn't work.

Here is my code :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import sys
from time import gmtime, strftime
import time
import os

dirname=str(strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S", time.localtime()))
newpath = "%s" %dirname
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
    os.makedirs(newpath)

# both MOG and MOG2 can be used, with different parameter values
backgroundSubtractor = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()

# apply the algorithm for background images using learning rate > 0

for i in range(1, 10):
    bgImageFile = "background%s.jpg" % i
    print ("Opening background", bgImageFile)
    bg = cv2.imread(bgImageFile)
    backgroundSubtractor.apply(bg)

# apply the algorithm for detection image using learning rate 0
    stillFrame = cv2.imread("object1.jpg")
    fgmask = backgroundSubtractor.apply(stillFrame, learningRate=0)

    cv2.imwrite('%s/fgmask.jpg' %dirname, fgmask)
    img1 = cv2.imread('%s/fgmask.jpg' %dirname)

    gray=cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret,th2 = cv2.threshold(gray,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
    morphed = th2.copy()
    morphed = cv2.morphologyEx(morphed, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel, iterations=5)
    morphed1 = cv2.morphologyEx(morphed, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel, iterations=17)

    cv2.namedWindow("image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.resizeWindow("image", 1000, 700)
   cv2.imshow("image", morphed1)

    _, contours,_ = cv2.findContours(morphed1, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    contours = list(filter(lambda cnt: cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 10000 and cv2.arcLength(cnt,True) > 1000, contours))

    for cnt in contours:
        print("aire = ", cv2.contourArea(cnt))
        print("perimetre = ", cv2.arcLength(cnt,True))
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = np.int0(box)
        cv2.drawContours(stillFrame,[box],0,(0,255,255),10)

    if len(contours)>0:
        break


# show both images
cv2.namedWindow("image1", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("image1", 1000, 700)
cv2.imshow("image1", img1)
cv2.namedWindow("image2", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("image2", 1000, 700)
cv2.imshow("image2", stillFrame)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here are some photos :

The backgrounds :

[image: background1]

[image: background2]

[image: background3]

[image: background4]

[image: background5]

The objects :

[image: object1]

[image: object2]

[image: object3]

Comment: You forgot your code

Comment: Yes thanks ! Now it's okay :)